# How to find the maximal number of grasshopers?

Tags: combinatorics

There are k grasshopers on 10 × 10 chessboard. Each of them has a fixed initial direction (parallel to one of the sides of the board; so there are 4 choices). Once the time starts, each second each of them jumps one square in a chosen direction and once it ends up in the last square in his row/column, it turns back and starts jumping in the opposite direction (turning back takes no time). It occured that no two of these grasshopers ever land on the same square of the board. What is the maximal k for which it is possible?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: The title doesn't match the body of the question. In the body you're asking for the maximal number of grasshoppers, whereas the title asks for the expected number of grasshoppers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my attempt.

Noticing that once we have one grasshopper in a row/column  in a direction, we cannot have any other in the same direction. Since there will be a time that they occupy the same square.

If you think a 2x2 board, you can have 4 grasshoppers, in each row, or column you have one moving in the same row/column, and another jumping out.

In a bigger board, you won't be able to add another grasshopper moving in the same direction of a previous in the same row/column.
SO, in a 4x4 you can fit 8, only adding 4 more, 2 in each extra row/column.

So in a 10x10 you can fit 20, you can see in each case by drawing a square board, and labeling lets say row movement with A, and column movement with B. The direction does not matter since they change it.
All you have to do is a kind of sudoku, were you can never have two A's or B's in the same row/column. And it does not matter how you start to place A and B, you will only be able to fit 2*n grasshoppers in a n*n board.